# Angular track by $index issue

Tags: angularjs

i'm using ng-repeat to render my html here is the code-snippet

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="feed in feeds  | orderBy:'title'">
    <p class="status-text">
        {{feed.title}}
        <a ng-href={{feed.link}} class="status-url">
         {{feed.link}}      
       </a>
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This successfully sorts the list but gives an error ,**Error:[ng-repeat dupes]** . I saw the documentation and modified the ng-repeat line to be

```
<li class="live_mvc_element" ng-repeat="feed in feeds track by $index | orderBy:'title'">
```

i added track by $index , the error was resolved , but its not getting sorted now . Whats the solution so that the error gets resolved and the list gets sorted too ??

Comment: Move the track by part to the end, after the orderBy.

Comment: For reference this is a known issue. Angular documentation has been updated to show it must be at end of statement. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5520

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this: `feed in feeds | orderBy:'title' track by $index"`

Source: [github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5520)